# jQuery - detect <video> onEnded

Tags: jquery, html, video

I have a page where I have to detect when the video has finished playing, so content can be displayed.. I'm using `<video src="link" autoplay></video>` for playing it and

```
$("video").bind("ended", function() {
            //Do stuff here...
        });
```

for detecting when it's done.. No idea why this isn't working.. Any help is appreciated!

[EDIT]
This works when I right-click the video and click 'Show Controls' while it's playing for the first time. So strange..

[EDIT]
Code seems to be working in IE9 now, but only in IE9..

Answer (score 0):

What if rather than using jQuery for the bind, you go more of a straight-JS route? Does this work for you?

```
$('video')[0].addEventListener('ended', function() {
    //do stuff
});
```

Comment: I'm using Chrome, but I tested it on all browsers, or rather, tried.. The video didn't play on any other but Chrome, could this be a HTML5 support issue?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to bind the event from the document

```
    $(document).bind('ended', function(e){

    });
```